# Close Modeless Userform

Tags: vba, forms, ms-word, modeless

How do I close a modeless form when a user clicks outside the form's window in Word VBA?

`UserForm_Deactivate` does not get invoked when I click outside the modeless form. It only get invoked when I show another form.

Comment: `outside the modeless form` Where exactly? In the workbook?

Comment: @SiddharthRout sorry, I am using Word.

Comment: I have deleted my answer.